# Text Files Matter

Tags: java

enter image description herei'm working on a project that writes and reads in text files , these are two functions for reading and writing from text files :

```
public void writetofile()
{
    String bucky4[]={custname,custlname,agee,address,id};
    for(int i = 0; i < bucky4.length; i++) {
         try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("records.txt", true)))
         {
             String s;
             s = bucky4[i];
             bw.write(s);
             bw.newLine();
             bw.flush();
         }
         catch(IOException ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error In File");
         }
    }
}

public void filereader (){
    int i=0;
    Object[] options = {"OK"};
    try
    {
       FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("records.txt");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
       String strLine;
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

       while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
       {
          sb.append(strLine +"\n");
       }
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString());
      }catch(Exception e){
          JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Error", "Customers", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
     }
}
```

the problem is whenever I read from file , details are gonna be printed out without any specific format , like this :

1. micheal
2. jackson
3. 22
4. c-.8.16 pri sero
5. d20

and i'm looking forward a function that helps me format it like this :

1. first name : micheal
2. last name : jackson

   ```
         ......,
   ```

   mention that I can't use constructors , and any help is appreciated

Comment: 1. Please format your code to make it readable. 2. Please show us a sample of your input. 3. Please describe the desired output format in detail. 4. Please describe what you have already tried.

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html

Comment: You can also use String#format: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/how-to-format-string-in-java-printf.html

Comment: I can't use a picture , if you do email me , I can send you my screenshots there , desired format is like this : name : james , age : 22 , but now it just prints out james,22 , i've tried to do it with constructor and it didn't came out like the way i wanted it , and there were many errors , anyway I've edited my question , hope you understand..

Comment: Is the input file csv?

Comment: No , it's a text file

Comment: Why can't you just append `first name` and `micheal` together?

Comment: If I do that , all of my data's in file are gonna have firstname at the back of them ....

Comment: You can use an array. See my answer

Comment: Why use an array to make a data structure?

Comment: @DaveNewton I wasn't really sure what OP is trying to do, so I just offered a suggestion.

Comment: @peeskillet I was *talking* to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a String array to hold the values

```
String[] titles = {"first name: ", "last name: ", ...}

int i = 0;
while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
{
    sb.append(titles[i] + strLine +"\n");
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: I've defined a segment of code for reading like this :catch(Exception e){
          JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Error", "Customers", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);   , so it just appears when I try

Comment: which means there is an exception and something's wrong with my codes

Comment: Why dont you put `e.printStackTrace()` instead of JOptionPane to see what the actual exception is.

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at assignment.Clerck.filereader(Clerck.java:437)
 at assignment.Clerck.existcustomer(Clerck.java:462)
 at assignment.Clerck.menu(Clerck.java:99)
 at assignment.Assignment.main(Assignment.java:69)

Comment: The error occurs at index 5, meaning you don't have 6 items in the array. If you're trying to print more than one set, you need to reset the `i` back to 0 after each set.

Comment: and how can I do that ?

Comment: Let me ask you, the method, is it supposed to print just one set (lastname, first name, ....)? Or is the method supposed to print more than one set? If so, how many sets are there. I just assumed the method supposed to only print one set because you are trying to display it in a JOptionPane

Comment: In my project , whenever I chose to register a customer one set of ( first name , last name , gender , age, address , id ) will be created , so yea ... it depends on how many times I register a new customer , but still 2-3 set is okay with me

Comment: There isn't a need to reset then because the method only prints one set. It's because your program loops through the entire file in the method. You need to give it a stopping point. But if you think about it, when you read from the file, it will always read the entire file everytime you call the method. What was the output before you used the array? Did it show all the people in the file? That's what I don't get

Comment: Say you write two set to the file. Then you try and read. The reader will read through the entire file and print two sets? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yea , before this method , It was displaying  all the customers ... as much I've registered , the function prints out everything in file

Comment: It's ok with me , if two or three set of  (first name , last name , gender , age , address , id ) appears , but if we could program it in a way that it formats first five lane like that , then second fives lanes the same , then third five lanes the same , .....

Comment: Add it after the `sb.append` and delete the other `i++`

Comment: public void filereader (){
String[] titles = {"first name: ", "last name: ", "gender" , "age","address"};
  int i=12;
  Object[] options = {"OK"};
  try
  {
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("records.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

  while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
  {
  sb.append( titles[i] + strLine +"\n");
  i++;
  }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString());
  }catch(Exception e){

Comment: I've just did i=12 , and i++ , plus the array ofc

Comment: WHy did you make `i = 12`? That makes no sense. There is no index 12 in the array. `i` should start at 0. You didnt see my earlier comment about the `if`. I don't see that added. Comment that start `"Ok you do want to reset."`

Comment: ok , I made i=0 and added that "if" you've mentioned , now the result is different , the first five are ok , they are name , last name , gender , age , adress , but after these 5 the rest are all address...

Comment: You added this entire block `if (i == 4) {i = 0;} else {i++;}`, replacing the original `i++`?

Comment: Yes sir i've added the entire block , you've made i ==4 , so only  first 5 are gonna be in desired format

Comment: Mistake change `i ==0;` to `i = 0;` in that block

Comment: wow man , you've got me amazed , we are very close , it's just one output wrong , I mean like in front of customer name is blank and customer name is written in front of customer last name , till the end it's like this , but it's in the right format :) so we are very close ! ! ! omg !

Comment: You mean it's all in one straight line? Not different lines?

Comment: different line , not all of them are in the same line , each one is in different line

Comment: So it's like this `[space] first name [nextline] Michael last name [nextline] Jackson addres [nextline] ...`?

Comment: firstname [nextline] lastname : micheal [nextline] gender : jackson [nextline] age : male [nextline] address : 22 [nextline] id : sri petlaing c9 [nextline] firstname : d20 [nextline] lastname : .......

Comment: I'm guessing you have line spaces in you file?

Comment: OMG , man , my problem is solved , and I really don't know how to thank you , you've been very very kind to me coming through all the steps , commenting  , I really appreciate it , Thanks a loootttt

Comment: ofc I do , anything else I can do just let me know !